# How to fetch maximum record using the particular channel _id in elasticsearch 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch

i have multiple document in each channel id and i want sort descending order in view column by channel id.

```
 {
   "query":
    {
    "match":{
        "channel_id":"UCQOd1f6pYldvhgvdQ_ktpGA"
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "video_views":{
        "sort": {
              "views": "desc"
            },
            "_source": ["channel_id", "views"]
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to group by channel Id  and return documents under channel ids

Comment: i want to group by channel id and return maximum value

Comment: i have multiple document in same channel id I want to return maximum views column

Comment: will you be filtering by channel id, Is it just one channel Id or multiple channel Ids?

Comment: one channel id only i want to filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get top 1 document sorted on views column

```
{
  "size":1,  --> get top 1 documnet
  "query": {
    "term": {   --> term query to filter on channelId
      "channel_id.keyword": {
        "value": "UCQOd1f6pYldvhgvdQ_ktpGA"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [      ---> sort on views column
    {
      "views": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Use Max aggregation

```
  {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "channel_id.keyword": {
        "value": "UCQOd1f6pYldvhgvdQ_ktpGA"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "views": {
      "max": {
        "field": "views",
        "missing": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting view value is null

Comment: {
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "views": {
            "value": null
        }
    }
}

Comment: i used channel_id.keyword but now it will be getting all document and still maximum value is null

Comment: which column i want to mapping?

Comment: output of Get <index-name>/_mapping. and any sample document

Comment: {
    "webtvasia_dash": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                    "channel_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                                
                "views": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: I have updated query, If it doesn't work provide a sample document

Comment: @RameshKumar Glad could be of help